# How to create a subtract method in a Math class?

Tags: php, oop, class, methods, subtraction

I am studying OOP and this is my first study project.

I created a Math class and also created an add method. But when I am trying to create a subtract method I don't know where I am getting a problem.

Please kindly help and give me information where I can get more detailed information on OOP.

```
<?php

class Math
{
    /**
     *
     * @return int  
     */
    function add()
    {
        $args = func_num_args();
        $sum = 0;
        $i = 0;

        for ( $i; $i < $args; $i++ )
        {
            is_int(func_get_arg($i)) ? $sum += func_get_arg($i) : die('use only integers, please');
        }
        return $sum;
    }

    function subtract()
    {
        $args = func_num_args();
        $sub = 0;
        $i = 0;

        while($i < $args)
        {
            $sub = func_get_arg($i);
            if (is_int(func_get_arg($i)))
            {
                is_int($sub - func_get_arg($i));
            }    
        }
        $i++;
        return $sub;
    }
}
```

I am calling this class in my index.php like this:

```
<?php
    include("Math.php");

        $c = new Math();
        $result = $c->subtract(100,10,20,45);

        echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: What should the outcome be of your subtract method for the values given above?

Comment: Your Math object has no own internal state on which the methods could operate on. This has nothing to do with OOP. You basically just grouped some more or less related functions into a class.

Comment: code inside 'while' - you overwriting $sub by each argument, and nothing more, no more "=" here.

Comment: $i++; placed after 'while', so $i will be always less than $args

Comment: @Bart: I'm guessing `25` or `-175`, but `25` seems more likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few small problems here:

1. Your loop won't ever terminate because the incrementing of $i is outside of your while loop.
2. The setting of $sub the first time should happen before the while loop.  I assume your subtraction function is meant to subtract the latter arguments from the first argument.  Right now, $sub is reset every pass through the loop.
3. $sub's value is never updated by the subtraction operation in your loop.  You need to assign a new value to $sub based on the subtraction.  You can use the -= shorthand for this just like you used the += shorthand in your add() method.

A working solution would look like this:

```
$sub = func_get_arg( $i );         // At this point $i == 0

while ( $i < $args ) {             // Loop while $i is less than the number of args
    $i++;                          // Increment $i
    $operand = func_get_arg( $i ); // Name the argument for clarity

    if ( is_int( $operand )) {     // Make sure the $operand is an integer
        $sub -= $operand;          // Update $sub by subtracting $operand from it
    } else {
        // Do some error handling here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for you to watch this video 
 [The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc).

This might help you to understand OOP better, and one of examples in the talk is very similar to one you are trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

The functional line `is_int($sub - func_get_arg($i));` is incorrect.  I think you intend to use this as a ternary operator and add additional logic.  Here is my rewrite:

```
public function subtract() {
   $args = func_get_args();
   $sub = array_shift($args);
   foreach ($args as $arg) {
      is_int($sub - $arg) and $sub -= $arg
         or die('use only integers please');
   }
   return $sub;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do that using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and [`bcsub()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcsub.php) (or other subtraction function):

```
$sub = array_reduce(array_slice(func_get_args(), 1), 'bcsub', func_get_arg(0));
```